# Query one table and if data is not there, query another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have store the same data in two tables: tableA and tableB. I want to select first from tableA, and if there is no data, I want to used tableB. tableA and tableB hold exactly the same data. I used tableB for archiving. There maybe times when we delete data from tableA but it will still be there in tableB.

```
$q = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id='1'");
if($q->fetchColumn==NULL){
    $q = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE id='1'");
}

foreach($q->fetchAll() as $data):
     echo $data['name'];
endforeach;
```

The problem with this code is that it returns from tableB whereas tableA data is there. How to solve this problem? Please help.

TableA

```
     id, name, age
     1   john   45
```

TableB

```
   bid, id,   name,    age
    1    1  old john    45
```

If there is no data in tableA, I want the query to select from tableB. But if there is data in TableA, I want to select from it(tableA). My code outputss from tableB.

The errors:

```
   fetchColumn()==NULL//does not output anything
   fetchColumn(0)==NULL//does not output anything
   fetchColumn==NULL//outputs from tableB
   fetchColumn==0//outputs from tableB
   fetchColumn()==0/does not output anything
```

Expected output: john

PHP Version 7.1.1

Comment: Use `fetchColumn()` and specify a column name in the query. Right now you're trying to assess *all* columns.

Comment: No, you want the first row, not the second. `fetchColumn(1)` gets the second row. *(Array counts start at 0)*

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I specify the column name but it does not work. No output.

Comment: Do you have any errors? You're not checking for them in your code, so you'll have to look in the error logs.

Comment: No errors. just a blank screen. No error logs as well.

Comment: Look in your error logs on your web server.

Comment: isn't `if($q->fetchColumn==NULL){` suppose to be `if($q->fetchColumn()==NULL){` ?

Comment: [That's what I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905797/query-one-table-and-if-data-is-not-there-query-another-table?noredirect=1#comment72911214_42905797) @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: I looked at php error logs and apache error logs. there is nothing there.

Comment: I find it hard to believe there is nothing in either log, especially the access log. What web server are you using?

Comment: @JayBlanchard clearly the code should give undefined index `fetchColumn`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, that still outputs from tableB.

Comment: add this at the top of your script : `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I am using xampp v3.2.2. I looked at all the logs. nothing like undefined is there.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, I did your suggestion. If I use fetchColumn()==Null, it does not output anything, just blank screen. And then if I use fetchColumn==Null, it outputs from the tableB. But I want it to output from tableA because tableA holds the data. Only if there is no data in the tableA that tableB should output.

Comment: try this condition `if($q->fetchColumn() == 0 ){`

Comment: Show us the data in tableA

Comment: the field in tableA are id, name, age, and the field in tableB holds bid, id, name,age. Each holds one row of data that is exactly the same. As you see tableB has bid as its primary key.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, `$q->fetchColumn() == 0` takes data from tableB.

Comment: How do u knw if this is returning data of table B? if the data are the same?

Comment: because you did not echo any `bid`

Comment: Because I prepended the name data with `old`.

Comment: Did you change the query to `"SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE id='1'"`?

Comment: No, I am using the code in my question except the fetchColumn part as you suggested.

Comment: I also said to [select a specific column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905797/query-one-table-and-if-data-is-not-there-query-another-table?noredirect=1#comment72911214_42905797). `fetchColumn()` needs a column to work with.

Comment: Yes I did. But it does not output anything.

Comment: Then there must be something else wrong. There is no way the code I wrote would fail if you're telling us everything.

Comment: what does http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php to the queries show? also make sure that there is absolutely "no data" in the first table. If there are `NULL` default values, `NULL` is not the same as "empty" and vice-versa. Run a `var_dump()` also everywhere.

Comment: @Fred, Thanks. the var_dump gives me `string(1) "1" `.

Comment: your table isn't empty then @ZoneSecurity but that's a dump from where/what?

Comment: thanks everyone for your help. I did solve my problem by adding another query to check whether the first query holds any data.

Comment: *"If tableA is empty I want to output data from TableA"* - I don't quite understand this. How can you output something if "nothing" is in there to start with? Or did you make a mistake in that comment?

Comment: @Fred-ii- he was trying to say, if the record does not exist on table A select on table B

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile well we all know who the real "God" of bashing is too, huh? Really a touch of class I'll say.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, why did you remove your answer? While you suggested using prepared query, you are also using unprepared in your answer. This is really confusing because you downvoted my answer. I did change my query to prepared one.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer. I did not use a prepared statement because you were hard-coding a value in your original question. Hard-coded queries do no require prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, have tested with the sample data you given, as Jay have said when u use fetchColumn() you need to specify atleast one column.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $q    = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE id='1'");
    $data = $q->fetchColumn(1); //name
    if ($data) {

        echo $data;

    } else {

        $q = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM tableb WHERE id='1'")->fetchall();
        foreach ($q as $data) {

            echo $data['name'];
        }

    }

    ?>
```

**Results :**

[image]

Results when id from table a is not 1

[image]

Comment: I did @JayBlanchard `fetchColumn(1)` this case the column is `name`

Comment: `SELECT * ` when fetchColumn()` counts at `(0)` its the id then at `(1)` its name

Comment: OK - I just tested and it works fine. Previous versions of PHP were a little more specific here.

Comment: I'm at php 7.1  previously could not get results

Comment: Yeah - I was testing earlier PHP when I did this and it seems 7.1 is a little more lenient.

Comment: in php 5.6 both your codes work with me as well. But I am using php 7.1.1 and it did not work.

Comment: I'm on php 7.1.1 and the code above works @ZoneSecurity as u can see the results

Comment: Yes I know. but the problem is that I have to write more codes. I want to put my code in one foreach loop.

Comment: Someone went through and Dv'd all of the answers, including the OP's

Comment: @JayBlanchard the Op deserve the dv, `WHERE id='$id'` maybe he needed to prepare the statement

Comment: The OP deserves the DV because the methodology is wrong. He may not be aware of the SQL Injection problems, but we typically do not DV someone because they've put themselves at risk.

Comment: I now know who DV'd all of the answers. See the new answer.

Comment: thought as much also @JayBlanchard

Comment: I did give the answer as accepted because it solved the problem. But what I actually used is my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic question, fantastic answers.

> If there is no data in tableA, I want the query to select from tableB. But if there is data in TableA, I want to select from it(tableA).

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$data = $stmt->fetch();
if (!$data) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    $data = $stmt->fetch();
}
echo $data['name'];
```

incredible complex logic with a lot of queries

Comment: So, answers which work get downvoted? I don't understand, please enlighten. It is one thing to disagree with method, quite another to DV just because you don't care for the complexity.

Answer (score -2):

Million thanks to everyone who helps me here. I solved my problem by adding another query to check the first query. This solution gives me what I want.

```
$id = 1;
$qr = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name, age FROM tableA WHERE id=:id");
$qr->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$res = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA WHERE id=:id");   
$res->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$row = $res->fetchColumn();
if( $row <= 0){ 
   unset($qr);
   $qr = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE id=:id");
   $qr->execute(array(':id' => $id));
}
$results = $qr->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $data):
     echo $data['name'];//output is john
endforeach;
```

Comment: this is not how u  use pdo

Comment: Yeah -- you're covering up for some other issue somewhere. There is *no reason* you should have to use another query.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Yes I know. I use prepare query in my real code. This here is for my solution in an easy to understand code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I fixed my code with prepared query. This answer is which works for me. Without using another query as you suggested, It did not work for me.